# Is it possible to handle timer tick event when it's stored in a session?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am storing a Timer, and a Array  in an asp.net session. I want to add a value to Array for each timer tick, Is it possible to handle Timer tick event when it's stored in a session ?

What i want is

```
Timer tm = new Timer() ; 
tm.TickEvent += TickEvent.... 
ArrayList[] arr = new ArrayList()
Session["A"] = arr ; 
Session["B"] = tm ; 

Void Timer_TickEvent ( .. , .. ) 
{ 
 ArrayList arr = Session["A"] as ArrayList ; 
 arr .Add ("VALUE >>> > " ) 
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? Give some detail.

Comment: [Each timer "Tick" causes a PostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer(v=vs.100).aspx). It works like any other PostBack and life-cycle event such as a button click. The session state is available during the the PostBack.

Comment: It won't work: when the Timer tick fires, Session won't be available, because there is no `HttpContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you storing Array in Session , its ok and you need to update session in every tick of timer when array value updating. Example:

```
String[] arr=GetData(); // GetData return string of array

Session["Response"]=arr; // Add arr in session.

**In timer event**

string[] arr=(string[])Session["Response"]; // casting
arr.add("value"); // array updating
Session["Response"]=arr; // stored in session
```

Comment: This is not what I want becuase I want to store Timer and Arraylist both in Session. You just tell me to store Array in Session but not timer. So I am afraid this is not what i want.

Comment: What are actually want with the storing timer in session..?

Comment: This won't work: when the timer tick fires, Session will no longer be available.